# how i can save the code VB in excel after closed the sheet

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have some problem..i write code VB in the excel 
but when iam closed the sheet excel and open the sheet again 
the code VB has been clear. i don't need that.
i need this code saved in the sheet excel after i close the excel
any way for this problem?!
and this my code VB.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 4 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Cells(Target.Row, 13).Value = Time$
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for your macro is good, nothing wrong with it.
Are you saving your file with the extension "xlsx"?
If so the macro will be removed. you need to save your file with the extension "xlsm". Macro enable file.